# Can a penalized site be indexed again

Tags: google, domains, ranking, penalty, expired-domains

I have an expired domain it is penalized in google can it be reindexed? I think it is penalized due to some bad backlinks  if I disow the bad backlinks in google webmasters can it be reindexed?

Comment: Related Matt Cutts video from 2014: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-EdhaMDXho

Comment: Yes i did it recently but it took too much time to show Google that the domain is clean now. Time is indefinite so be patient if you are doing the right thing.